# How to align radioButton and textView in a radioGroup?

Tags: radio-button, radio-group

hi i am working on my own app,and i have a doubt on---

How to align radioButton and textView in a radioGroup?
As i have to manage many radioButtons and TextViews in  the same radioGroup,in which only one radiobutton is to be checked at a time.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue on my own, i have assigned all the radio button to the same radio group which solved the problem of multiple selection.